# There is a problem with fetching and parsing data with React and Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from api and show it with React.
However I could see that errors and I'm difficult with parsing json response from api.
I think that it will be solved if I make response as array.
I don't know how to make it.

[image]

page.js

- I try to fetch data from API by Native hook and useEffect
- I checked API by Postman. So it is working well.

```
function Customers(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/contacts")
      .then((response) => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
          setError("Invalid response: ", response.status);
      } else {
          setError(null);
      }
          return response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json);
      });
  });

  if (error !== null) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
  } else {
      return (
        <DashboardLayout>
        <>
      <Head>
        <title>
          Data
        </title>
      </Head>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          py: 8
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth={false}>
          <Box sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
            <CustomerListResults customers={data} />
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
    </DashboardLayout>
        );
  }
}

export default Customers;
```

list_component.js

- I made a table. I would like to show API data this table.
- I try to use slice and map to parsing data. but it is not working.

```
export const CustomerListResults = ({ customers, ...rest }) => {
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(25);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  const handlePageChange = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  return (
    <Card {...rest}>
      <PerfectScrollbar>
        <Box sx={{ minWidth: 1050 }}>
          <Table size="small">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                  Date
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Name
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
            {customers.slice(0,limit).map((customer) => (
                <TableRow
                  hover
                  key={customers.id}
                >
                  <TableCell>
                    <Box
                      sx={{
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        display: 'flex'
                      }}
                    >
                      <Typography
                        color="textPrimary"
                        variant="body2"
                      >
                        {customers.created_date}
                      </Typography>
                    </Box>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    {customers.user_idx}
                  </TableCell>
                 </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Box>
      </PerfectScrollbar>
      <TablePagination
        component="div"
        count={customers.length}
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        page={page}
        rowsPerPage={limit}
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

CustomerListResults.propTypes = {
   customers: PropTypes.array.isRequired
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `data` on initial load is equal to an empty object, and object doesn't have a slice method as it's a method for an array.

One solution is set an inital value for data to an empty array.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Instead use a null value initially and when mapping/slicing, do `customers?.slice` (notice the optional chaining operator). Also, having the value null/undefined initially will return false in `if` checks.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to solve this issue.

Comment: But I prefer the array solution as it doesn't require value checking on the side of HTML.

Comment: set initialState as array and when redering the data just puts cutomers && cutomers?.slice it should solve the problem

Comment: @AmirShahzad You don't need to add `cutomers && cutomers?.slice` if you set the initial value as an array, as an empty array is already a true value.

Comment: Also `cutomers && cutomers?.slice` together is redundant, as customers?. will already check the customers' value, and will not execute `slice` method except customers has a defined value, so `customers && customers.slice` or `customers?.slice`

Comment: Good @Mina you are right

Comment: @Mina I tried. It looks like working. However. I saw another error. Could you help me? also I could see just single same data all the table.

Comment: Error say that Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. so I changed customers.id -> customer.id. After that I remove error, still I can see same data in table

Comment: @JaeseoLee, Sure, I will try to help you, Do you mean that just one item is repeated in the table?

Comment: And Yes, you need to change all text interpolation from customers. to customer.

Comment: @Mina Thanks!. yeah right. Also I changed all the customers. to customer. but  it is same.

Comment: Ok, please create a new question, provide full code using any live editor like codesandbox so I can debug the issue, and please provide me with the question link.

Comment: @Mina Thanks. I think that there is problem with data haha. Have a nice day. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, have a nice day too.